# setting expect variable with grep output

Tags: grep, expect

I use an expect script to login to a remote server; to do so, I need to set up 2 variables:

```
set username <user>
set password <passwd>
```

I grep `user` & `passwd` from a file. How to set up expect variable with grep ouptut?

when I try:

```
set username "grep '(?<=username:)[^<]*' file"
set password "grep '(?<=password:)[^<]*' file"
```

expect says:

invalid command name   "^<"
    while executing
"^<"
    invoked from within

"send "grep -oP '(?<=username:)[^<]*' file""

(file "./test" line 11)

when I try:

```
set username "grep -oP '(?<=username:)[\^\<]*' file)"
```

expect says:

can't read "(grep -oP '(?<=username:)":

no such variable
    while executing

"send "$(grep -oP '(?<=username: )[\^\<]*' file)""

(file "./test" line 11)

I am just wondering what could be the correct syntax.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I think you need `set password [exec <yourcommand>]`

Answer (score 2):

You'll want something like this:

```
set fid [open file r]
set contents [read $fid]
close $fid
lassign [regexp -inline {username:([^<]+)} $contents] x username
lassign [regexp -inline {password:([^<]+)} $contents] x password
```

You're having a hard time with Tcl syntax, so start with the [Tcl tutorial](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html).